# Increment time interval by 15 minutes in javascript

Tags: javascript

As stated in the example below, I would like to create an array that is incremented with 15 minute interval.. Irrespective of the `getTime()` , the array should start from **12.00 AM** until **11.45 P.M.** Example:

```
[12.00 AM, 12.15 AM, 12.45 AM, 1.00 AM ... 11.45 P.M.]
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what exactly you're trying to achieve. Could you please provide some code showing what you have already tried to achieve this?

Comment: This question is poorly worded - what you are trying to achieve is ambiguous. Are you trying to create a timer that only updates its display every 15 minutes? Or do you just need to store every 15 minute time possible in an array?

Comment: I found the solution. Thank you guys for looking.
    var hours, minutes, ampm;
    var time = [];
    for(var i = 0; i <= 1440; i += 15){
        hours = Math.floor(i / 60);
        minutes = i % 60;
        if (minutes < 10){
            minutes = '0' + minutes; // adding leading zero
        }
        ampm = hours % 24 < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
        hours = hours % 12;
        if (hours === 0){
            hours = 12;
        }
        time.push(hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm); 
    }
alert(time);

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just hardcode that array?

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for looking. I found the solution of what I needed.

```
  var hours, minutes, ampm;
    var time = [];
    for(var i = 0; i <= 1440; i += 15){
        hours = Math.floor(i / 60);
        minutes = i % 60;
        if (minutes < 10){
            minutes = '0' + minutes; // adding leading zero
        }
        ampm = hours % 24 < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
        hours = hours % 12;
        if (hours === 0){
            hours = 12;
        }
        time.push(hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm); 

    }
document.getElementById("Time").innerText = time ;
```